# wget kinogo.net 403 Forbidden

Tags: linux, proxy, selenium

Делаю запрос wget'ом на сайт http://kinogo.net, лог получается такой:

> ---request begin---
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (linux-gnu)
> Accept: */*
> Host: kinogo.net
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> ---request end---
>
> ---response begin---
> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
> Date: Sun, 05 Apr 2015 02:37:09 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Connection: keep-alive
> Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d581a7377798cae42e6d530c858ab03921428201429; expires=Mon, 04-Apr-16 02:37:09 GMT; path=/; domain=.kinogo.net; HttpOnly
> Cache-Control: max-age=15
> Expires: Sun, 05 Apr 2015 02:37:24 GMT
> X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
> Server: cloudflare-nginx
> CF-RAY: 1d21de956c42158f-FRA
> ---response end---

Получается 403 Forbidden, наверное, из-за плохих заголовков.
Пробую ловить заголовки со своего браузера:

> ---request begin---
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: kinogo.net
> Connection: keep-alive
> Cache-Control: max-age=0
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
> ---request end---
>
> ---response begin---
> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
> Date: Sun, 05 Apr 2015 02:48:43 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Connection: keep-alive
> Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d81a82368470347d5786e6d6f3b31781b1428202123; expires=Mon, 04-Apr-16 02:48:43 GMT; path=/; domain=.kinogo.net; HttpOnly
> Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=pf6ot2v375oceh1krjjtjtebf2; path=/; domain=.kinogo.net; HttpOnly
> Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
> Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
> Pragma: no-cache
> Set-Cookie: dle_user_id=deleted; expires=Sat, 05-Apr-2014 02:45:56 GMT; path=/; domain=.kinogo.net; httponly
> Set-Cookie: dle_password=deleted; expires=Sat, 05-Apr-2014 02:45:56 GMT; path=/; domain=.kinogo.net; httponly
> Set-Cookie: dle_hash=deleted; expires=Sat, 05-Apr-2014 02:45:56 GMT; path=/; domain=.kinogo.net; httponly
> Server: cloudflare-nginx
> CF-RAY: 1d21ef8690ef01b1-FRA
> Content-Encoding: gzip
> ---response end---

Ставлю wget'у такие же заголовки:

```
wget -d --header="Cache-Control: max-age=0" --header="Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" --header="User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36" --header="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch" --header="Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8" http://kinogo.net
```

Отправляю:

> ---request begin---
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
> Host: kinogo.net
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> Cache-Control: max-age=0
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
> ---request end---
>
> ---response begin---
> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
> Date: Sun, 05 Apr 2015 02:56:49 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Connection: keep-alive
> Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d073eddf5fef12567851e1e473830867c1428202609; expires=Mon, 04-Apr-16 02:56:49 GMT; path=/; domain=.kinogo.net; HttpOnly
> Server: cloudflare-nginx
> CF-RAY: 1d21fb675ffa01b1-FRA
> Content-Encoding: gzip
> ---response end---

То есть заголовки мы отправляем идентичные(порядок же не играет роли, правда?), а ответ получаем другой(404 Not Found), но уже не 403 Forbidden.

На сервере крутится selenium webdriver, пробую с ним, браузер хром 41, язык python3:

> ---request begin---
> GET http://kinogo.net/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: kinogo.net
> Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
> Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
> ---request end---
>
> ---response begin---
> HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
> Date: Sun, 05 Apr 2015 01:37:56 GMT
> Content-Type: text/html
> Transfer-Encoding: chunked
> Connection: keep-alive
> Set-Cookie: Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d0b1d19d69c52f3f9f38eb968211bda211428203483; expires=Mon, 04-Apr-16 01:37:56 GMT; path=/; domain=.kinogo.net; HttpOnly
> Server: cloudflare-nginx
> CF-RAY: 1d2187d5ff401583-FRA
> Content-Encoding: gzip
> Connection: close
> ---response end---

Отличия видимы только в трех строках:

> GET http://kinogo.net/ HTTP/1.1
> Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36

Последнюю можно проигнорировать, т.к. это самый обычный user agent, который у всех разный. А ответ все тот же 404. Даже не знаю, ставить прокси на браузер открываемый и инжектить туда свои заголовки, вместо Proxy-Connection Connection, но сыграет ли это какую-то роль? Если у кого есть какие-то догадки - подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, что на сервере введено ограничение на используемые User-Agent.
Если сделать так, то сработает, ответ 200:

```
wget --user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.118 Safari/537.36" http://kinogo.net/
```

**UPD:** Попробуйте сделать запрос с другого IP адреса, возможно на Ваш наложены какие-нибудь ограничения, например, если Ваш сервер генерировал много запросов к сайту из-за парсинга.

Comment: В том-то и дело:
`HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found`

Comment: Я выполнил запрос на своем сервере, у меня 200. Мне кажется, что до kinogo стоит либо прокси, либо Ваш сервер в блэк листе...

Comment: Попробуйте поставить user-agent яндекса) http://help.yandex.ru/webmaster/robot-workings/check-yandex-robots.xml#robot-in-logs

Comment: Тоже 404, я так полагаю IP хостера в блеклистах Cloudflare.